# No provision to convert Spark DataFrame to AWS Glue DynamicFrame in scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

There is no equivalent of the below code to convert from Spark DataFrame to Glue DynamicFrame, is it intentional, what is the workaround?

```
# Convert to a dataframe and partition based on "partition_col"
partitioned_dataframe = datasource0.toDF().repartition(1)

# Convert back to a DynamicFrame for further processing.
partitioned_dynamicframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(partitioned_dataframe, glueContext, "partitioned_df")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
# Convert Spark's DataFrame to Glue's DynamicFrame
val partitioned_dynamicframe = DynamicFrame(partitioned_dataframe, glueContext)
```